# Send Firebase data from View Controller to View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, segue

I currently have a UITableView inside a ViewController named `MainViewController` which loads all my content from the Firebase database. I also have another ViewController named `DetailsViewController` which loads data from whatever cell is clicked via a segue. What I am trying to do is create another ViewController named `CommentViewController` and load info from the same cell that was clicked before (Segue comes from `DetailsViewController`).

This is how I currently have my Storyboard setup:
[image]

This is how I am currently loading data from `MainViewController` to `DetailsViewController`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
        if let indexPath = self.postsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let post = posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
            let postDetails = post["postID"] as? String
            let controller = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
            controller.postDetails = postDetails
        }
    }
}

// DetailsViewController
var postDetails: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(postDetails!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            self.title = dictionary["title"] as? String
            self.priceLabel.text = dictionary["price"] as? String
            self.ratingLabel.text = dictionary["rating"] as? String
            self.usernameLabel.text = dictionary["username"] as? String
            self.detailsTextView.text = dictionary["description"] as? String
         }
    })
}
```

How could I pass this data in the most simplest and easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to load data in your table didselect method of main controller and pass dictionary to detailsController and give value to all outlets. See Below code

```
MainController

 var dictDetails: [String:AnyObject]?
.
.
.
.
.



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let post = posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
                let postDetails = post["postID"] as? StringFIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(postDetails!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                  self.dictDetails = dictionary
                  performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
             }
        })

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {

                let controller = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
                controller.dictionary = self.dictDetails

        }
    }

    // DetailsViewController
    var dictionary: [String:AnyObject]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = self.dictionary["title"] as? String
                self.priceLabel.text = self.dictionary["price"] as? String
                self.ratingLabel.text = self.dictionary["rating"] as? String
                self.usernameLabel.text = self.dictionary["username"] as? String
                self.detailsTextView.text = self.dictionary["description"] as? String

    }
```

Need to take dictDetails Dictionary in mainController.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, but I am already passing the data for the DetailsViewController just fine but would like to know how to pass data to the CommentsViewController

Comment: same way you pass from main to details. Take public variable in commentViewController and give it's value in preparesegue in detailsView controller.

Answer (score 1):

As per sschunara's answer let me add extra code for your answer.

You have all detail in your `DetailViewController's` dictionary

```
// DetailsViewController
    var dictionary: [String:AnyObject]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = self.dictionary["title"] as? String
                self.priceLabel.text = self.dictionary["price"] as? String
                self.ratingLabel.text = self.dictionary["rating"] as? String
                self.usernameLabel.text = self.dictionary["username"] as? String
                self.detailsTextView.text = self.dictionary["description"] as? String

    }
```

Just agin you have to pass data same as like from `MainViewController-> Detail ViewController`

Now `DetailViewController -> CommentViewController`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showComments" {

            let controller = segue.destination as! CommentViewController
            controller.dictionary = self.dictDetails

    }
}
```

Pass whole dictionary or just Comment string as per your requirement and you can access that it in your `CommnetsViewController` and set that data into `lable`.

Hope this will clear your data passing concept.